# All of my JSON output (from Laravel API app) is contained within a data tag, how do I remove this?

Tags: php, android, json, laravel, api

I'm working on an API in Laravel that outputs JSON for an Android app to use. I'm working on the Laravel side and my friend is working on the Android side. We can connect the Android app to the API, but it can't access the data for some reason. The problem we think we have, is that all of the JSON output from Laravel is in a data tag, which the Android app can't access.

[JSON output from Laravel API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDUy7.png)

The code for all articles

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
      'status' => 'ok',
      'totalResults' => count($this),
        'articles' => ArticleResource::collection($this->collection),
    ];
}
```

The code for one article

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'source' => [
          'id' => $this->id,
          'name' => $this->name
        ],
          'author' => null,
          'title' => $this->title,
          'description' => $this->description,
          'url' => $this->url,
          'urlToImage' => null,
          'publishedAt' => $this->created_at,
          'content' => null
      //]
    ];
}
```

I've been searching for how and why it's all inside the data tag, or if that's even why we're having problems, but I can hardly even find other examples with Laravel outputting JSON in a data tag, never mind actually fixing it. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Let me know if there's more information/code/screenshots you'd like, thanks.

Edit: 
[Also, as well as all the articles, nested in the data tag is the pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG7yh.png)

Middleware code:

Authenticate.php

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

TrimStrings.php

```
protected $except = [
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
];
```

TrustProxies.php

```
protected $proxies;
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $addHttpCookie = true;
protected $except = [
```

(End of Middleware code)

[Not sure if this will be helpful, every occurrence of the word 'data' in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tTfA.png)

Comment: How are you accessing the API response? It should be available via `response.data`

Comment: seems you have some middleware which altering response. check enabled middleware.

Comment: on the client side try, parsing json because the json is sent in string format from one point to another, so u may not be converting it to json before accessing the data tag

Comment: Tim Lewis, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, I check my API output on either a google chrome, or postman

Comment: Jagad89, I just added my middleware code in an edit, there's also two other middleware files that have empty functions at the moment.

Comment: Danial, do you mean from the Android app (I'm not very familiar with this part), or from a browser or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do for single items.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    static::$wrap = null;

    return [
        'source' => [
          'id' => $this->id,
          'name' => $this->name
        ],
          'author' => null,
          'title' => $this->title,
          'description' => $this->description,
          'url' => $this->url,
          'urlToImage' => null,
          'publishedAt' => $this->created_at,
          'content' => null
      //]
    ];
}
```

If it has pagination links as you mentioned it simply forces data as it requires to store other metadata information. That's how resources work. Check this in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping), especially Data Wrapping and Pagination.

Your other options are not to use Resource and create your own output.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this at first. The data tag was never in the single items, only in the array. So if I remove the pagination, it should remove the need of a data wrapping all together?

Comment: Yup, that's the trade-off

Comment: Ah okay, I understand the data wrapping now, thank you so much. On first attempt there at removing it I've gotten an error, call to an undifined method, 'mapInto'. Not sure what this is, but looking in to it now

Comment: So I just swapped the ->paginate() for a ->get() instead of removing, and it works. Not entirely sure if that's how I'm supposed to do it, but hey, it's working haha. Thanks again Vladan, and everyone else who helped